# Find result str with regular expressions in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a input string:

```
$str1 = "some usefull text and garbage `~#@!&^*(()}{./";
$str2 = "`~#@!&^*(()}{./";

$result = Exclude with regular expressions all symbols from str1, which are in str2.
$result = "some usefull text and garbage";
```

What regular expression will simply delete all symbols which I specify? How can I filter it in a right way? Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need a regular expression for that:

```
$clean_str = str_replace(str_split($str2), '', $str1);
```

You may want to `trim` the resulting string.

Comment: Yeah, preferable to a `preg_repalce(...)`, IMO.

Comment: srt_replace - very nice results!! Thanx all a lot

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using regex:

```
$str1 = "some usefull text and garbage `~#@!&^*(()}{./";
$str2 = "`~#@!&^*(()}{./";

$pattern = preg_quote($str2,'/'); 
echo preg_replace('/'.$pattern.'/', "", $str1);
```

Outputs:

```
some usefull text and garbage
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the optional second param of `preg_quote(...)`.